# LINQ expression until to break a string

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Using LINQ I'm looking to break down the following path `string[]`, however I'd like to break it up to the point of the Binn folder.  Is there a WHERE UNTIL operator in LINQ?

```
c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe
```

What I'd like todo

```
var words = from word in thepath
where UNTIL thepath == "Binn"
select word;
```

Comment: Must you use LINQ for this? Can't you use the `Path` class: http://dotnetperls.com/getdirectoryname You can then `Split` the returned directory name to get each section of the path.

Comment: Because I wanted the full directory upto a certain point.  LINQ just seems a neater way of doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Enumerable.TakeWhile` extension method. AFAIK, there is no LINQ syntax for this.

```
var words = thepath.TakeWhile(word => word != "Binn");
```

Comment: Sorted TakeWhile was what I needed, thanks very much works a treat.

Answer (score 4):

First, split the path:

```
var parts = path.Split('\\');
```

To get the part up to (but not including) "Binn":

```
var start = parts.TakeWhile(p => p != "Binn");
```

To get the part after (and including) "Binn":

```
var rest = parts.SkipWhile(p => p != "Binn");
```

You can also use Skip or Take to consume or discard a specific number of items from the sequence.

Though if you just want the filename part of a path, use `Path.GetFileName`.

Answer (score 1):

off the top of my head

```
        var path = @"c:\ Program Files\ Microsoft SQL Server\ MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\ MSSQL\ Binn\ sqlservr.exe";
        var words = path.Split('\\');
        var filteredWords = words.TakeWhile(w => w != "Binn");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have used a regex

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
...
String path = @"c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe";
path = Regex.Replace(path, @".*\\Binn", "Binn");
```